# Problem with the Specular Glossiness node and Metallic Roughness

Tags: node-editor, gltf

Goodmorning everyone

I write because I have a problem with the Specular Glossiness node: I do not know how to connect it to Metallic Roughnes.

I'm creating a 3D file, to be exported to glTB 2.0 (glb) to create a 3D post on Facebook.
I downloaded Importer / exporter from [KronosGroup](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter), then I imported the Metallic Roughnes node onto my project on Cycles Render and later I imported also Specular Glossiness.

I was able to give a metallic look to my 3D element, but I would also like to give the effect of the reflection so that the Synapticweb logo that you see in my first pic, is reflected in the element that is below it.
[image]

**But I do not know how to do this.** 
Although I link the Specular Glossiness output to Metallic Roughnes, there is no Glossy effect.

Here is an example of my post: https://www.facebook.com/paginaprovaSynptc2018/posts/2225106837534167
[image]

**Can someone help me?**
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I guess that facebook's 3d viewer does not support real time reflections. Cycles uses raytracing to calculate the reflections while most online viewers use rasterization like game engines. In order to get reflections in these engines you would have to create reflection probes or screen space reflections (which does not seem to be supported by facebook yet).

Comment: Ok, But maybe it's possible by Blender 2.80 Beta ?

Comment: You can export Principled BSDF materials to glTF in the Blender 2.8 beta, although only certain nodes are supported. Documentation is still in progress, here: https://developer.blender.org/D4082. Facebook does support metal/rough PBR materials and realtime rendering.